# how to get rid of systemd plymouth service login prompt at boot?

Tags: boot, xubuntu, plymouth

I'm running xubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

I rarely reboot, so it's hard for me to pinpoint why it happened, but at some point I either installed something or an update got it in - now when I boot, before the login screen shows up, a text login prompt wants me to type login and password.

The only hint I have is the prompt is caused by plymouth service from systemd

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked to move the `systemd-ask-password-plymouth.path` and `systemd-ask-password-plymouth.path`. In Kubuntu 20.04 at least they are located in `/etc/systemd/system`.
Then I masked the service with `systemctl mask systemd-ask-password-plymouth.path && systemctl mask systemd-ask-password-plymouth.service`. This creates a softlink `systemd-ask-password-console.path -> /dev/null`.
After that there were some additional boot up issues after that, but they were specific for my system. If the boot up slows down significantly for you (for me it was >3min) just move the files back to `/etc/systemd/system`.

I was able to identify the service that slowed down my boot after removing the files by looking at `/var/log/boot.log`. Hope this helps.